# Are there file naming rules for python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

Environment 
    Python version : 3.4.2
    OS version : OS X Mavericks

Hi,

I wanted to do some web scraping example with python.

So, I created the script file and named it 'html.py'. ( in my project directory)

But, when I executed it with python3, it generates errors like this.

------------------------------------------- Error Msg -----------------------------------------------

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "html.py", line 1, in <module>
      from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
      from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
      from bs4.element import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 5, in <module>
      from bs4.dammit import EntitySubstitution
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py", line 11, in <module>
      from html.entities import codepoint2name
  File "/Users/tester/Project/Python/html.py", line 1, in <module>
      from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: cannot import name 'BeautifulSoup'
```

---

But, I installed 'BeautifulSoup4' by ' sudo pip3 install BeautifulSoup4 '.

And, I checked it is installed in the right path.

Strange thing was that I tried to import 'BeautifulSoup4' with python3 shell mode **in the different directory**(for ex. not in my project directory),

it makes no errors.

Errors appear only when I execute the script file in that directory. (where 'html.py' exist)

So, why is this happening?

And, errors are also disappered when I changed the script file name. (html.py -> test_html.py)

What's wrong with file name?

Am I not allowed to use module name as my script files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`html` is the name of [a standard module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html).

I'm guessing that, at some point, BeautifulSoup is importing this html module. However, Python will (by default) first look for modules in the directory of the script file you are running. So it will find and import your `html.py` instead of the standard module.

From the [docs on `sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path):

> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list,
>   path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to
>   invoke the Python interpreter

You could change the name of your script (good idea) or modify `sys.path` to change the order of where Python will look for modules (bad idea).

Comment: Naming user modules after stdlib modules (such as random.py) is a common beginner problem.  The docs have a module index one can check.  2.7.8 had 'htmllib', but 3.x has 'html'